# Google Apps Script - how to stop plain text email converting to Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

Tags: email, google-apps-script, text, base64

The plain text version of an email is getting encoded to base64.

It only gets encoded to base64 `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64` when it includes a text string longer than 256 characters. At 256 characters or less, no encoding is applied.

I'm checking the plain text using 'show original' in Gmail.

I've tried escaping special characters https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204218/1027723 but it makes no difference.

So this email body is fine (max text string length = 256 characters):

```
You can ** unsubscribe from this newsletter (https://script.google.com/a/macros/website.co.uk/s/7iInODLb2Vu5mZyN07tvBzni1CK6Ez15SQfrFMhW3AWhc6RlrtnKFTeFt85Y9djYvBOuT3ZGlv/exec?token=eyJuYW1lIjoiQWWsaXRpc3QgQ29udHMgIiwiaWQiOjM2OH0=&token=eyJuYW1lIjoiQWWsaXRpc3QgQ29udHMgIiwiaWQiOjM2OH0=WQiOjM2OH0MWQi)
```

But add one more character to that long string and it gets encoded to base64:

```
You can ** unsubscribe from this newsletter (https://script.google.com/a/macros/website.co.uk/s/7iInODLb2Vu5mZyN07tvBzni1CK6Ez15SQfrFMhW3AWhc6RlrtnKFTeFt85Y9djYvBOuT3ZGlv/exec?token=eyJuYW1lIjoiQWWsaXRpc3QgQ29udHMgIiwiaWQiOjM2OH0=&token=eyJuYW1lIjoiQWWsaXRpc3QgQ29udHMgIiwiaWQiOjM2OH0=WQiOjM2OH0MWQiM)
```

I'm sending using MailApp. To reproduce the error:

```js
const recipient = ''; // enter email address
const subject = 'test plain text email';
const plaintext = `You can ** unsubscribe from this newsletter (https://script.google.com/a/macros/website.co.uk/s/7iInODLb2Vu5mZyN07tvBzni1CK6Ez15SQfrFMhW3AWhc6RlrtnKFTeFt85Y9djYvBOuT3ZGlv/exec?token=eyJuYW1lIjoiQWWsaXRpc3QgQ29udHMgIiwiaWQiOjM2OH0=&token=eyJuYW1lIjoiQWWsaXRpc3QgQ29udHMgIiwiaWQiOjM2OH0=WQiOjM2OH0MWQiM)`;

function sendEmail() {
  MailApp.sendEmail(
    recipient,
    subject,
    plaintext)
}
```

The resulting plain text email ('show original' in gmail):

[image: test email result - bad]

The desired outcome:
[image: test email result - good]

The desired outcome is to send a plain text email including a string that exceeds 256 characters without it encoding to base64.

**Questions**

Does it matter that base64 encoding is applied to the plain text version?

Could it negatively impact spam filters?

**Thoughts and links**

- [Would using Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 for text and html email present any issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16207375/would-using-content-transfer-encoding-base64-for-text-and-html-email-present-an)
- Does the encoding happen to avoid lines that are longer than smtp is happy with? (see https://tools.wordtothewise.com/rfc/5321#page-63 # section 4.5.3.1.6)
- Base64 encoded plain text makes your mail 25% bigger than quoted printable.
- Focusing on accessible text/html is a better use of effort than lovingly crafting a text/plain alternative!

Comment: Please provide [mcve].  I tried it myself and I don't see the problem.

Comment: Thank you @Cooper it worked for you? I'll edit the question to be clearer.

Comment: Now I just a url in the email.

Comment: Hi @Cooper so I presume you are looking at the HTML version of the email and not the plain text version? What do you see if you select 'show original' and look at the message source? thanks

Comment: Nope I am looking at the plain text.  I provided no html

Comment: Ok where do you see the plain text email?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254790/discussion-between-topmarx-and-cooper).

Comment: so I'm trying to get rid of the base64 encoding, gmail doesn't show the text version any more, afaik stackoverflow.com/questions/…
so it's decoding the base64 encoding. The plain text version is in base64 encoding. To view text version of message, click on more and select ‘Show original’

Comment: The email looks like plain text to me

Comment: @Cooper have you checked to see there's no base64 encoding under 'show Original'?

Comment: Yeah I see the encoding there but I was just looking at the email and it looks like plain text to me.

Comment: You can elminate the encoding by removing the `https:` from the beginning of the strings

Comment: @Cooper by removing `https:` you are shortening the string length and that is why it works, not because `https:` affects the encoding. Remove the `https:` and keep the string length the same, and the problem remains

Comment: @TopMarx From `I notice your reply includes an htmlBody variable, but I create that separately so I'm not sure it's applicable. I didn't really understand what your code is doing. What is the benefit of enabling Gmail API? What are all the MIME version, mailData, boundaries, etc? I don't really understand it. Thank you`, I thought that my answer was not useful for your situation. In this case, I have to delete my answer. Because I don't want to confuse other users. I think that this is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for my poor skill again.

Comment: I added more characters to the front of the string.  It's not the length.  They just see the protocol and encode it.  But without the protocol they don't

Comment: I made a 300 character long random character string and they did not encode it

Comment: @Cooper ok thank you, how strange, I did that test and it did encode!

Comment: I just tested again, I went to this site http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/random-string-generator/ generated a 300 character string, sent an email, and it encodes to base64. I also tested with a random string of 256 character length, and that didn't encode to base64

Comment: I cannot confirm that.

Comment: My content type is plain text in both original and email

Comment: Cooper and Tanaike, thank you for your help, I've re-edited my question for clarity, I really appreciate your time looking into this